# TypeError: state.getIn is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm implementing immutable on my react project, using it with redux, making state an immutable object using fromJS() function (from immutable library). In my reducer file, everything works, I receive an action, I can set the new value using setIn() function, and I can use getIn() function to access state.

But when I get state from connect() function, using mapStateToProps, even if console.log shows an apparently immutable object, I can't use immutable functions, like toJs() or getIn() here. I receive always this error: `TypeError: state.getIn is not a function`.

***My index.js file***

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { template as templateAction } from './actions';
import withReducer from '../../../reducer/withReducer';
import templateReducer from './reducer';

export const Template = ({ name, template }) => (
  <Button onClick={template}>
    {name}
  </Button>
);

Template.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  template: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state is equal to', state);
  return (
    {
      name: state.getIn(['templateReducer', 'name']),
    });
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  template: () => dispatch(templateAction()),
});

export default compose(
  withReducer('templateReducer', templateReducer),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(Template);
```

***Result of console.log(state)***

[Result of console.log(state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgNox.png)

PS: When I don't use immutable state, everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `state` inside `mapStateToProps` function is an object with one property of 'templateReducer' that has a value of type `Map`.

I'm a bit rusty with my React knowledge, but maybe sharing the code for `templateReducer` would be helpful.

What does `withReducer('templateReducer', templateReducer)` do with the reducer function?

Seems like it is setting the state from the reducer to the key `templateReducer` before sending it to the `mapStateToProps` function. (maybe??)

Probably, changing this function to access the State before using immutable methods will remove the error.

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state is equal to', state);
  return (
    {
      name: state['templateReducer']?.getIn(['name']),
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use connect from `griddle-react` not `react-redux`.